# impala-shell inserts odd control characters into the response to a non-interactive query

Tags: bash, sed, impala

I run a query in impala to check that a condition is met in a table and store the number of rows in a bash variable:

```
UC=$(impala-shell -r -q "select count(1) from table where condition=1" -d $DB -i $HOST -B)
```

UC now holds the row count where condition is one, in this case, no rows meet this condition:

```
echo $UC
 0
```

my comparison to check the value of UC fails because it has weird control characters in the front.

```
if [ "$UC" == "0" ]; then echo 1; else echo 0; fi
0

echo $UC | hexdump
0000000 5b1b 313f 3330 6834 3020 000a
000000b
```

When I try to remove non-digits from the input, I get weird output

```
echo $UC | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g'
10340
```

What is happening here and how can I format the result to do my simple comparison?

Comment: Can you show output of `echo -n "$UC" | xxd`

Comment: @anubhava sure output is `0000000: 1b5b 3f31 3033 3468 2030 0a              .[?1034h 0.`

Comment: try `echo $UC | sed 's/^\([^0-9]\{2\}\)*//g'`. Your are using a double 8bit code char. Better is to convert first in 8bit char code.

Comment: @NeronLeVelu thanks, when I used that command I got `?1034h 0` which sheds light on the previous output. If I chain that with another that takes advantage of the space I can see it: `echo $UC | sed 's/^\([^0-9]\{2\}\)*//g' | sed 's/^.* //g'` outputs `0`. I don't know if the space will always be there but this works for now.

Comment: so make it in 1 sed until the final good solution `echo $UC | sed 's/^\([^0-9]\{2\}\)*//;s/.* //'`  (`g` are not needed normaly due to first `^` and generic in second sed action)

Comment: Can you tell `impala-shell` to produce just the raw output, without the escape sequences for coloring/cursor control/whatever that is? That would be better than trying to post-process the output...

Comment: @twalberg I don't disagree with you but the `-B` option should have done just that.

Comment: @rici thank you, the `TERM=ansi` bit did the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ESC[?1034h` is an `xterm` control sequence meaning "Interpret <kbd>meta</kbd> key, sets eighth bit." (A useful list of `xterm` control sequences is [here](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html).) So presumably `impala-shell` has noticed that you have an `xterm`-compatible terminal, and is trying to initialize it for interactive use, even though the `-q` command-line option renders that pointless.

You can probably avoid the problem by invoking `impala-shell` with the `TERM` environment variable set to `ansi`, which will prevent terminfo-based programs from emitting the `smm` control sequence:

```
UC=$(TERM=ansi impala-shell -r -q "select count(1) from table where condition=1" \
                            -d $DB -i $HOST -B)
```

You might also be able to convince `impala-shell` that interactivity is unnecessary by redirecting `stdin`:

```
UC=$(impala-shell </dev/null -r -q "select count(1) from table where condition=1" \
                             -d $DB -i $HOST -B)
```

Either way, a feature request to the authors of `impala-shell` seems reasonable. I think the problem occurs at line 142 of impala_shell.py (`self.readline = __import__('readline')`); `import readline` has the side-effect of initializing the underlying readline library, which then effectively does `tput smm`; if `$TERM` indicates that `smm` exists, it will be sent. There's nothing wrong with initializing the `readline` library if you're going to use it, but in the case of a non-interactive shell you are not going to use it. So one solution would be to check for interactivity before importing readline (there is already a fallback in case the import fails). Another option might be to delay importing readline (and hence initializing it) until it is actually needed.

Comment: @JeffHammerbacher: Cool. Now that I see that impala-shell is open source, I took a glance at the source and added a note about a possible fix (to my answer, not the bug report, but hopefully whoever handles the bug will take a look at the link you provided.)